# Locking other application

Tags: android

may be some of you know Clean Master application and that it can block other application by pattern lock,so i wanna do an application like Clean Master but only with function of locking other application by password,please help me with it
Thank you for reading and answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application` launches are not broadcasted, so you cannot know when an app is launched, the only thing you can do is

- creating a `service` running every x milliseconds
- this service will check what (non system) application is on front
- once you understand what app is on front, kill that app
- pop a password input box
- if that password is correct relaunch that application

Comment: I think best thing you can do is start understanding those two concepts: [Process Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle) and [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)